# common code for all methods in a controller class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have 10 controllers that use the same block of code but I can't figure out how to write the code once and use it everywhere.

I have to define an object called:

> requiredStructuralSupportParameters

, then set 3 fields in the object.

This is one of the controller methods that uses it:

```
public class StructureController : Controller
{   
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        var requiredStructuralSupportParameters = new Structure.RequiredInfo()
        {
            Steel = "1500y",
            Concrete = "5500l",
            Rebar = "95000y"
        };

        var response = callToAPI(requiredStructuralSupportParameters);

        return response.Results;
    }
}
```

I have tried taking that code out and putting it at the top of the controller class and making it public, but then my controllers can't see it and I get nullreferenceexception errors.

So it only works when I put it directly in the controller methods.

Is there a way to make this so that all controllers can re-use the same block of code?

Comment: Create a factory method or create an overload of `callToAPI` where you do not have to pass in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class StructureController : Controller
{   
    protected YourType _requiredStructuralSupportParameters;

    public StructureController()
    {
        this._requiredStructuralSupportParameters = new Structure.RequiredInfo()
        {
            Steel = "1500y",
            Concrete = "5500l",
            Rebar = "95000y"
        };
    }
}
```

then have your other controllers inherit your `StructureController`:

```
public SomeController : StructureController{

   public IActionResult Index() {
      var response = callToAPI(this._requiredStructuralSupportParameters);

      return response.Results;
   }
}
```

haven't tested it but i hope you get an idea

Comment: While this answer is technically fine, I would caution against using a base controller for something like this. C# does not support multiple inheritance, so you need to be very cautious about what you choose as your single source of inheritance. Something like done here would be better done either via config or a class of constants.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i sure agree. also, there is an architectural question of: does this code belongs to controllers world at all (it doesn't, in my opinion) with all fat vs thin controller story. It should be better fit for some service injected with custom options. but, i guess that exceeds the scope of this question.